# Returning value of one function in javascript to next javascript function in the same page

Tags: javascript

I am not able to return the value of `pos` from function `loc` to its next function initialize.
Function pos gives me current latitude and longitude and I want to use these values in the next javascript function initialize. The value of pos on running initialize function gives undefined.

```
function loc() {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
           pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
           return pos;
           });

            }


     function initialize() {
          var x = loc();
          alert(x);
        centralLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6940741,-73.9869325);
        var request = {
          location: centralLocation,
          types: ['clothing_store'],
          rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE
        };

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',initialize);
```

How do i use the value of pos in my initialize function in `var centrallocation` i.e I want to pass the value of pos in `var centrallocation` as a parameter.

Comment: Don't tag JavaScript as Java. They are very different

Answer (score 0):

It is `undefined` because `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous. You should place your logic inside the callback of `getCurrentPosition`

```
function initialize() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

        centralLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6940741,-73.9869325);
        var request = {
            location: centralLocation,
            types: ['clothing_store'],
            rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE
        };

    });
}
```